# How to create a timestamp column in a PySpark dataframe that includes all time intervals?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column named "interval_date_time".

"interval_date_time" is timestamp like "2022-01-01:00:00:00", "2022-01-01:00:30:00", "2022-01-03:01:00:00", "2022-01-03:02:30:00", "2022-01-03:14:00:00".

| interval_date_time |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01:00:00:00 |
| 2022-01-01:00:30:00 |
| 2022-01-03:01:00:00 |
| 2022-01-03:02:30:00 |
| 2022-01-03:14:00:00 |

However, it doesn't have time values starting from "00:00:00" until "23:30:00" for all dates.

I want to create a new PySpark DataFrame with a column that has a timestamp datatype.

The difference with the original DataFrame is that this new DataFrame has every 30 minutes time intervals for all dates in the original DataFrame.

Example values will be like :

"2022-01-01:00:00:00", "2022-01-01:00:30:00", until  "2022-01-01:23:30:00".
And the same for "2022-01-03"

| interval_date_time_new |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01:00:00:00 |
| 2022-01-01:00:30:00 |
| 2022-01-01:01:00:00 |
| .... |
| 2022-01-01:23:00:00 |
| 2022-01-01:23:30:00 |
| 2022-01-03:00:00:00 |
| 2022-01-03:00:30:00 |
| 2022-01-03:01:00:00 |
| ..... |
| 2022-01-03:23:30:00 |

Any idea how to do that in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `sequence` function with `interval 30 minutes`.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    select(func.to_date('interval_ts').cast('timestamp').alias('dt')). \
    dropDuplicates(). \
    withColumn('ts_seq', func.expr('sequence(dt, date_add(dt, 1), interval 30 minutes)')). \
    withColumn('ts_seq', func.expr('slice(ts_seq, 1, size(ts_seq)-1)')). \
    select(func.explode('ts_seq').alias('interval_ts_new')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------+
# |interval_ts_new    |
# +-------------------+
# |2022-01-01 00:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 00:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 01:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 01:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 02:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 02:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 03:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 03:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 04:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 04:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 05:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 05:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 06:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 06:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 07:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 07:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 08:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 08:30:00|
# |2022-01-01 09:00:00|
# |2022-01-01 09:30:00|
# +-------------------+
# only showing top 20 rows
```